# Scalability of Python Module / Package system to large projects

Tags: python, module, namespaces, package

I would like to have a nice hierarchy of modules for a large
project.. (Python seems to get in the way of this) I am confused about
the distinction of modules and packages and how they relate to the C++
concept of a namespace. For concreteness my project is a compiler and
the code generation phases want to query properties from some set of
abstract representations which are maintained in a different directory
(actually far away in the hierarchy)

The problem can be stated as:

Ass: Let a.py and b.py be two source files somewhere in the project hierarchy

Then: I want to refer to the functions defined in b.py from
a.py -- ideally with a relative path from the well-defined root
directory of the project (which is /src). We want a general-purpose
solution for this, something which will always work..

Dirty hack: It sounds absurd but my putting all sub-directories that contain .py on this
project into PYTHONPATH we will be able to reference them with their name, but with this
the reader of the code loses any sense of hierarchy & relation about the different project
classes etc..

Note: The tutorial on Python.org only mentions the special case of referring from a file c.py to  a file d.py placed in its parent directory. Where is the generality that makes
Python scale to really large projects here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Suppose b.py is in `/src/dir1/dir2`, then assuming `/src` is on PYTHONPATH, you can import it from a.py using `import dir1.dir2.a`.  This assumes that dir1 and dir2 have been made into packages by placing a file called `__init__.py` in them.

Comment: If that is the case the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the question, but let us see.

Suppose I have the following package scheme (`__init__.py` files excluded for readability):

```
foo/baz/quux/b.py
foo/baz/quux/quuuux/c.py
foo/bar/a.py
```

My `foo/baz/quux/b.py` file contains this:

```
def func_b():
    print 'func b'
```

and my `foo/baz/quux/quuuux/c.py` is:

```
def func_c():
    print 'func c'
```

If the root directory which contains `foo` (in your case, `src`*) is in the Python path, aur `foo/bar/a.py` file can import any other module starting from `foo`:

```
import foo.baz.quux.b as b
import foo.baz.quux.quuuux.c as c

def func_a():
    b.func_b()
    c.func_c()
```

And one can use the `foo/bar/a.py` this way:

```
import foo.bar.a as a

a.func_a()
```

Have you tried it? Did you got some error?

* When you deploy your project, I do not believe the root will be `src` but let us maintain it simple by omitting it :)

Comment: sorry the root i meant is of course not root of the project, this has <doc>, <lib>, <man> and others in it; but on the other hand we say the src_root(which i meant) is the LEAST folder such that any folder in the project with a "__init__.py" in it is a descendant of src_root in the filesystem hierarchy. Hereby LEAST is based on the usual depth-order of tree ( a < b if the path from a to the root passes through b)

Comment: Also I think my problem has been solved and this question can thus be closed